# Is there a way to bind to Keyboard.FocusedElement?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, focus

I would like to have a property that is always bound to the currently focused control.

I have seen two ways to get the currently focused control.

One is using Keyboard.FocusedElement.
The second is traversing the visual tree.

Since I want to know every time the focused element changes the visual tree traversal seems like it would be running a lot of code all the time.

But Keyboard.FocusedElement does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  So I can't just bind to it normally.

**Is there a way to get it to let me know when it changes?**

**(Or some other way to have a property that is always set to the currently focused control?)**

**NOTE:** Clearly I could add an event onto each control and have it update a property.  But I have a lot of controls.  I want to avoid having to attach an event to each of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to subscribe to the [Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocus Attached Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.gotkeyboardfocus.aspx)

> Occurs when an element receives keyboard focus.

Here is an example which subscribes to this event OnStartup. You could use an attached behavior which does this and updates an attached property which you can bind to for example.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement),
            Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocusEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(Keyboard_GotKeyboardFocus), true);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    private void Keyboard_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was truly a fabulous answer!  Thank you so much for pointing me to this.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I was able to help :)