# implement CanExecute MVVM light using ICommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, icommand, canexecute

I have a program, where a button should only be active if the corresponding userControl has focus.

I am using MVVM light, and got a command implementing the ICommand interface.

I have tried using the Keyboard.FocusedElement, but this returns nothing.

This is the code for the command (Note that it just returns true right now to get it working, this sis of course what i'm trying to fix):

```
class AddItemToNodeCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("fokuselement er: " + Keyboard.FocusedElement);    
       return true;
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Parameter er: " + parameter);
        Debug.WriteLine("fokuselement er: " + Keyboard.FocusedElement);

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

From the viewmodel:

```
public ICommand AddItemToNodeCommand { get; private set; }
AddItemToNodeCommand = new AddItemToNodeCommand<object>();
```

And finally some of the XAML:

```
<RibbonButton SmallImageSource="../Images/whatever.png" Label="Attribute" Command="{Binding AddItemToNodeCommand}" CommandParameter="Attribute"/>
```

I haven't posted the xaml for the userControl, but the idea is that when the userControl has focus, the CanExecute should be true.. I thought it would work with the Keyboard.FokusedElement, but I was wrong. What can I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you button is child of the usercontrol you want to check focus on?

Comment: Nope, the button is part of another userControl (A ribbon control)

Comment: Looking at the functional point of view, I think that as soon as you move focus from the userControl then the button will become disabled. So I don't think the button remains useful in functionality. Correct me if I have not understood your problem.

Comment: Hi Palak. Yeah I see your point. Even though what I would have done probably won't work then, I still don't get why the Keyboard.Focus doesn't return anything. The thing i'm trying to achieve is, that when I click on the userControl, the button should be available, until the focus is moved to something else (Like another userControl)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is a bit fickly.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367013/is-there-a-way-to-bind-to-keyboard-focusedelement) for a solution involving  attached behavior and overriding the `Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocusEvent`. I tried it, and it seems to work.

Otherwise, you can bind to `IsKeyboardFocused` or `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`. Just put this in your xaml for a quick example:

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBox Name="test_txtbx" >Hullo</TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="test_txtbx_2">Hullo 2</TextBox>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=test_txtbx, Path=IsKeyboardFocused}"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=test_txtbx_2,Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin }"></Label>
    <Button Click="TestClick">test me </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

The label shows if the matching textbox has focus.

(Here's an [old article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx) which says focus is funny as well .. dunno if still relevant though).